# Run ''.join code through each list in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list that looks like this - the list was made from an xml file using the following:

```
for node in tree.findall('.//name'):
    mylist = list(node.text)
    print mylist

#output-- 
['M','e','d', 'i','a','n',' ','C','o','n','d','o',' ','V','a','l','u', 'e']
['M','e','d','i','a','n',' ','H','o','m','e',' ','V','a','l','u','e']
['H', 'o', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'T', 'y', 'p', 'e']
```

1) I want to concatenate the strings in each of the individual lists in this list

2) Once all the values in each individual list is concatenated, I want to combine the concatenated values from the multiple lists into a singe one.

I tried the following for concatenating the strings but it only returns the last list [Home Type] multiple times in a list:

```
def joinlists(lists):

    results = []
    for list1 in lists:
        results.append(''.join(lists)) 
    return results
print joinlists(makelist)
```

I need the list to look like this:

```
 mylist2 = ['Median Condo Value', 'Median Home Value, 'Home Type']
```

Comment: `mylist =[node.text for node in tree.findall('.//name')]`, Typo here --> `results.append(''.join(list1))`

Comment: `node.text` is clearly already a string, why are you calling `list()` just to want a string back from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join nothing.

Your problem is `list(node.text)` made a string into a list character by character.

```
>>> list('hello world')
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

If you want a single list, then you can use list-comprehension

```
names = [node.text for node in tree.findall('.//name')]
```